# Python Path Double Backslash when opening file causing error

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I'm trying to open a file like this:

```
with open(str(script_path) + '\\description.xml', 'w+') as file:
```

where `script_path` is equal to this:

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '\\.tmp')
```

When I run this I get an error that there is no such file or directory because when it tries to open the file it sees the whole path as a string, including the escape strings. Is there any way around this?
Obviously `.replace()` won't work here as it won't replace the escape string. Hoping there is a clever way to do this within the os module?

Comment: Why are there two backslashes? If `description.xml` is in the same directory as the script, the relativr path is just `description.xml`

Comment: I think I did this so it would be in the tmp folder, although I guess I could just use ```'.tmp/description.xml'```

Comment: I recommend using os.path.join to create a path instead of string concatenation. This might help avoiding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you're adding two backslashes. You can simply create the path using a single forward slash (Linux based) or backslash (win). Something like this:

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/tmp/description.xml'
```

However, better way to achieve this would be to use `os.path.join` as suggested by nomansland008.

```
>>> import os

>>> parent_dir = "xyz"
>>> dir = "foo"
>>> file_name = "bar.txt"
>>> os.path.join(parent_dir, dir, file_name)
'xyz/foo/bar.txt'
```

You won't have to bother about whether the string has slash(or not). It will be taken care by join.
In your case it can simply be:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'tmp', 'description.xml')
```

Should work, provided the files and directories exist.